# Create variables in Django views.py and access them at later point

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have the following two functions in views.py:

```
def foo(request):
    class_instance = SomeClass()
    return HttpResponse('whatever')

def bar(request):
    # here I want to access class_instance
```

Initially, `foo()` is called, and at a later point `bar()` is called, in which I want to access the variable `class_instance`.

Is there any way of accomplishing this while neither using `request.session` nor Django models (e.g. `django.db.models`)?

(NB: I had some luck with global variables in views.py, but this is probably a bad idea anyway and somehow didn't always work)

Comment: No. Where would they be stored? If you want to persist them between requests, you need to put them somewhere. This is the *exact use case* of the session: you should explain why you don't think that is suitable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clear response. In my specific case, in which the website is more of a local GUI than a remotely accessed webpage, I disliked the fact that the user could eliminate the variable by clearing the session. But okay, I could probably live with that. The question then becomes: what is the best way to send back request.session to the client, when `foo()` isn't actually supposed to update the website in any way? `render(request, '')`?

Comment: `request.session` doesn't need to be sent back to the client, it's stored on the server; the client will already have a session ID from the initial request. But you do need to send something back to the client, surely; you don't want them to just see a blank page, do you?

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. I think you right then that  `request.session` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your variable as a module constant, especially if it's not prone to changing much.

```
CLASS_INSTANCE = SomeClass()

def foo(request):
    return HttpResponse('whatever')

def bar(request):
    # here I want to access CLASS_INSTANCE
```

Then both methods will have access to that, <del>but keep in mind, that functions can't change constant's value this way</del>.

PS: Actually you **can** change the value of the global:

```
CLASS_INSTANCE = SomeClass()

def foo(request):
    global CLASS_INSTANCE
    CLASS_INSTANCE = SomeClass() # new instance
    return HttpResponse('whatever')

def bar(request):
    # here I want to access CLASS_INSTANCE
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After trying a bit, i found that this method had problems in case of asynchronous processes that should change CLASS_INSTANCE. But, obviously that was not part of my original question!